# Why isn't there a character-set-client-handshake RDS parameter for MariaDB 10.2 or 10.3?

Tags: mariadb, amazon-rds

MariaDB has a parameter, [--character-set-client-handshake](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqld-options/#-character-set-client-handshake), that can allow you to specify that the server should ignore the character set being specified by a client connecting.

On RDS, when you create a parameter group for a MariaDB v10.1 instance, this parameter is available for customization.  But on v10.2 and v10.3 parameter groups, it is NOT present.

This parameter is also not present on [the RDS list of MariaDB parameters not supported by MariaDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MariaDB.Parameters.html).

Searches for this have yielded no info.. can i be the only one that is looking for the character-set-client-handshake parameter for MariaDB v10.2 on RDS?

Comment: File a bug report with MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing this problem. It seems like a bug with MariaDB. What I did was I changed init_connect value to set names (charset of your choice) to automatically set charset on connection.